# engine performance problem

Tags: misfire, saturn, intermittent-problems, power-loss, ion

My question is about my 2004 saturn ion 2.2L. Engine misfires and looses power intermittently. I plugged the code reader and gave me PO341 (camshaft position sensor A circuit range performance (bank 1 or single sensor).

Answer (score 1):

The 2.2L L61 engine doesn't use a traditional camshaft position sensor. The ignition control module senses firing events. Then generates a CMP signal to send to the PCM. This could be a wiring issue, a failure in the ICM or a secondary ignition problem (e.g. spark plugs/coil pack).

A clean CMP signal needs to be confirmed at the PCM and make sure that the coil pack can produce a strong enough spark on cylinders 1 & 4.

Comment: Excellent explanation; this is just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Buy a repair manual and look up what to do for that code.  Have you done a tune up recently?  Maybe the sensor needs to be replaced?